# Get value in a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi i have something like:

```
var obj = {
    level1 : {
        level2 : 'value'
    }
};
```

Also another object:

```
var returnData = {
    value: "level1.level2",
     anotherThing: "level1"
};
```

I want to loop through all the keys from the `returnData` object and get those values from the `obj` object. I have this but can't get the wanted value for the key `value` in returnData:

```
var dataToreturn = [];
$.each(returnData, function(k, v) {
    dataToreturn[k] = obj[v];
});
```

So the final result would be:

```
dataToreturn[value] = 'value';
dataToreturn[anotherThing] = {
   level2 : 'value'
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3u4vxwc5/8/

Comment: Try printing your `k v` values, you'll see that the first iteration `v`is just a string, and doing `obj['level1.level2']` isn't going to do what you want it to do, you might have to manipulate that string inside or previous to your loop.

Comment: are there any javascript functions to achieve this? or should i just manipulate the string like spliting etc

Comment: Your data is not valid. And it does not make sense to use normal keys on an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both `forEach()` and `reduce()`. `forEach` to loop object keys and then `split()` each value at `.` and then use `reduce()` to loop those values and add to array.

```js
var obj = {
  level1: {
    level2: 'value'
  }
};

var returnData = {
  value: "level1.level2",
  anotherThing: "level1"
};

var dataToreturn = [];

Object.keys(returnData).forEach(function(e) {
  var keys = returnData[e].split('.')

  keys.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
    if (keys[i + 1] && r[e]) return r[e]
    else if (r[e]) dataToreturn.push(r[e])
    return r;
  }, obj)
})

console.log(dataToreturn)
```

Comment: @Ardit Meti See update in case you have something like this https://jsfiddle.net/3u4vxwc5/10/

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
level1 : {
    level2 : 'value'
}
};

var returnData = {
value: "level1.level2",
 anotherThing: "level1"
};

Object.keys(returnData).forEach(key=>returnData[key]=returnData[key].split(".").reduce((val,key)=>val[key],obj)||returnData[key]);

console.log(returnData);
```

Iterate over all keys of return Data and reduce it to a value.